# Custom URLs in Joomla

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, redirect, joomla

In `Joomla`, how can I change the form of my website `URL`s?
As an example I want to change the link:

```
mysite.com/index.php?option=com_blankcomponent&view=default
```

to somthink like:

```
mysite.com/news
```

How can I do this in Joomla?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to do 2 things:

1. Enable SEO URLs. First change

   > htaccess.txt

   on your site's root to

   > .htaccess

   then go to System -> Global Configuration in the administration
   panel and set "Search Engine Friendly URLs" to "Yes".
2. Under "Menus" in the administration panel - change the relevant menu item's Alias to "news" and click "Save".